# Unset element in array

Tags: php, arrays, element, unset

I want to unset 1 element in the array.
If for example I use GET and ?group=k

How do I unset "k" in the array?

This is the array:

```
$groups_array = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','a2','b2','c2','d2','e2','f2');
```

I have tried

```
   if(isset($_GET['group'])) {
     unset($groups_array[1]);
     $new_groupps_array = array_values($groups_array);
   }
```

which works fine but where it shows [1] it needs to be a letter so I know how to unset it?

Hope you understand
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example, if you wanted to delete `'a'` value, you simply do:

```
$key = array_search('a', $groups_array); // search for key of my value
if($key !== false){
  unset($groups_array[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You can use `array_search` function to retrieve the value based key and unset the array accordingly.

```
 if(isset($_GET['group'])) {          
      $key = array_search ($_GET['group'], $groups_array);
      unset($groups_array[$key ]);
      $new_groupps_array = array_values($groups_array);
  }
```